# Bindings in span are not working

Tags: xamarin.forms

Span is working fine with static data but I want it to work dynamically too. 
  Can anyone help?

```
<Span Text="{Binding Text}" ForegroundColor="Fuchsia"/>
```

I tried this peace of code but it's not working.

Comment: What version of Xamarin.Forms are you using?

Comment: have you set the BindingContext?

Comment: yes i have set the BindingContext.

Comment: is Text a public property on the class the BindingContext is set to?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

`<Span Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay}" ForegroundColor="Fuchsia"/>`

Span bindings are defaulted to one time bind only in xamarin forms.

Answer (score 2):

**Multiple fonts and color in single label, we can do it just write given peace of code:**

```
public FormattedString FormattedText
    {
        get
        {
            return new FormattedString
            {
                Spans = {
                    new Span { Text = "Me: ", FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold},
                    new Span { Text = DynamicString}
                        }
            };
        }
        set { }
    }
```

Comment: 'Me ' as a hard code text used and DynamicString is as dynamic data used in same string.